# Lerna runs only number of packages simultaneously

Tags: node.js, reactjs, lerna

I have 5 packages that lerna should start on localhost when you run it, I usually need to run all 5 to compare changes and speed up development/testing.

It starts only 4. Randomly removes one package, like is caped to 4 somehow, maybe thats a normal behaviour that I don't know about, or maybe it's some npm cap?

It's lerna 4.0.0 and
react 16.14.0"

Answer (score 1):

You could try to change the global option [--concurrency](https://github.com/lerna/lerna/tree/main/core/global-options#--concurrency), its defaults is calculated by the count of logical CPU cores.

> How many threads to use when Lerna parallelizes the tasks (defaults to count of logical CPU cores)

```bash
$ lerna publish --concurrency 5
```